# Access Struts 2 variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts2

I have set a Struts variable in my JSP:

```
<s:set var="actionName" value="stockCountFind.action" scope="request" />
```

In the javascript function I access it using

```
function getAttributeAndGoToAction() {
  var actionName = <s:property value="#actionName"/>;
  alert(actionName);
}
```

But when I try to call the JS function. It says it isn't defined.

Comment: What isn't defined? What does the generated HTML look like? You need to provide more information/do more research

Comment: @JuanMendes it says the javascript function is not defined. The html is not genertaed of this line.

Comment: If the function is not defined, then you have much bigger problems because. You need to to some debugging on your own, do some printlns before and after. How can we help if you don't show what's going on? I'm sure something was output that could help understand the problem.

Comment: @JuanMendes why are you assuming I haven't done anything. The problem is with the line in which i try to get the property using the strut tag. If I remove this line. The function executes. I have also tried logging on console. It works. Now if you know how to solve my porblem, kindly share but don't assumt things. Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming you haven't told us what you have tried. How could I know If you don't give us details?

Comment: Looking at the rendered page, or following the JS console trail, will explain the error. The reason Juan is asking what you've actually tried is because you clearly didn't look at either the rendered JS nor follow what the JS console is telling you, because if you had, the problem would be obvious.

Comment: Here's a tip, the output of your HTML?JS would be `var actionName = someAction;` which is invalid (needs quotes around it). Or if the property is empty, it's completely syntactically wrong: `var actionName = ;`. Try adding quotes around the JS variable you are trying to create, and you should properly escape it for the quotes you're using. Best way is to JSONify the data. `var actionName = "<s:property value="#actionName"/>";` (This will fail if there are quotes in the name, converting to JSON is the ideal)

Comment: As @DaveNewton pointed out, there's likely an error on your console also because `<s:property value="#actionName"/>` is outputting blank.

Comment: Way less information provided. Consider adding logs or console o/p when you ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
function getAttributeAndGoToAction()
{
  var actionName = "%{actionName}";
  alert(actionName);
}
```

just surround your variable with ***%{*** and ***}***

I use such variables in .jsp in this way:

```
<s:set var="myVar"><c:out value="${myVar}"/></s:set>
<s:a href="%{myVarRef}" title="%{myVar}" target="_blank">
   ...
</s:a>
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything in my jsp too or just the js change you mentioned in the answer would work?

Comment: You need to change only js function. But be in mind that your function should be located in the same .jsp file. If your function located in separate file (.js) which you include in .jsp, it will not work in any case, 'cause scope of visibility of variables is your jsp file

Comment: @Saramali I've just updated my answer. Looks like there is no need to use 's:property' tag in your js function. Just %{actionName} or try ${actionName}

Comment: This will not work as-is; you cannot use OGNL notation in arbitrary places. You need to either use JSP EL, `${actionName}`, or continue to use the tag. In addition, the value should be JS-escaped, in case it includes any double-quotes.

Comment: You are just suggesting different syntax, not explaining what the error is. Answers should not be guesses or "try this"

Answer (score 0):

Define variable inside the JS not in the JSP like below.

```
<s:set var="variableName"><s:property value='variableValue'/></s:set>
```

In my case I store value in the session, so set variable as,

```
<s:set var="variableName"><s:property value='#session["attributeName"]'/></s:set>
```

In your case, if you store value in the request, then it like,

```
<s:set var="variableName"><s:property value='#attr["attributeName"]'/></s:set>
```

Then can access variable along with # mark like `#attributeName` for operations.

Example: `<s:if test="#attributeName.equals('ABC')"></s:if>`